# how to get the 5 digits number concatenated with financial year

Tags: c#

A textbox should contain 5 digits and financial year,for ex:00001/financial year.
If 1 is entered in first textbox it should concatenate with 4 zero's slash financial year

based on system date and display in second textbox.when 123 is entered it should

display with 00123/financial year.In this way the number of digits in the second

textbox should be 5 and length of textbox should not exceed 15 characters.
financial year(13-14) is in this format.

```
    int CurrentYear = DateTime.Today.Year;
    int PreviousYear = DateTime.Today.Year - 1;
    int NextYear = DateTime.Today.Year + 1;
    string PreYear = PreviousYear.ToString();
    string NexYear = NextYear.ToString();
    string CurYear = CurrentYear.ToString();
    string FinYear = null;
    if (DateTime.Today.Month > 3)

    FinYear = CurYear + "-" + NexYear;

    else

    FinYear = PreYear + "-" + CurYear;
    string strfst = FinYear.Substring(2, 2);
    string strlst = NexYear.Substring(2, 2);
    string strfnyr = strfst +"-"+ strlst;
```

In this manner i got financial year.with this financial year i need to concatenate the 5 digit number.

Answer (score 2):

The [PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function is what you are looking for.  `textBox1.Text.PadLeft(5, '0')`

Comment: when I entered digit it works perfect like 00001,but when I entered A1 it is showing 000A1.I need to display zero's before 1.Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

May be just use appropriate *formatting*. If you want to represent 
financial year as "08-09", "09-10", "11-12" etc:

```
  // Financial year computing
  int year = DateTime.Now.Month > 3 ? DateTime.Now.Year + 1: DateTime.Now.Year;
  // Converting financial year (as a period) into string
  String strfnyr = String.Format("{0:00}-{1:00}", (year - 1) % 100, year % 100);
```

You can even output all the edit box data in one go:

```
   int prefix = 1; // <- 5 digit prefix mentioned in the question  
   int year = DateTime.Now.Month > 3 ? DateTime.Now.Year + 1: DateTime.Now.Year;
   String result = String.Format("{0:00000}/{1:00}-{2:00}", prefix, (year - 1) % 100, year % 100);
```